# psychic mode in kopete

Tags: instant-messaging, kde-4, kopete

Is there a 'psychic mode' plugin for kopete?
Psychic mode is a pidgin plugin that opens up the chat dialog as soon as someone starts talking with you, before message is sent. i'm looking for the same functionality in kopete.

Comment: let me check my crystal ball...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go : [kopete psyko 0.1](http://opendesktop.org/content/show.php?content=121585),

Same plugin [download link 2](http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Communications/Chat/kopete-psyko-55357.shtml)

Hope this helps!

Comment: how should i compile that? there are no compiling instructions... but it seems to be exactly what i want! thanks

Comment: built it with <code><pre>cmake .</pre></code>
but still nothing happened... maybe it's the 0.1 status...

Comment: haven't used this as I'm not a kopete user, wish I could be of more help. I tried to look this up if there was a specific install procedure but I couldn't find any. A possible lead could be to find out how to install plugins to kopete.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=217603 this thread is about installing another plugin to kopete if its of any use.

Answer (score 0):

In Configuration->Behavior->General, there is "Message Handling": "Open messages instantly".

Comment: but it doesn't actually open the message when people type, but when people send... i want it to open whenever people start typing (a.k.a. psychic mode)

Comment: Switch to Google Wave?

Comment: Or back to Pidgin